# Comment Walker vs. Comment Callback

Tags: walker, comment-form, comments, comments-template

I've been messing around with custom comments this week and I'm trying to figure out when I'd want to use a walker and when I'd use a callback...

There's some things I can't quite figure out how to change, but the one that's been driving me mad is how to add classes to the children `<ul>` tag:

`<ul class="children">`

Are there certain things a comment walker can do that a comment callback can't?... or vice-versa? And is one of these "better" to use as a theme developer? For example, I know that a lot of menu plugins don't work when a theme is using a custom menu walker.

Anyway, here's an example of the **exact same comments**, but one is being output using a walker and one is using a callback... What am I missing here? Why the need for both of these?

### Comment Callback

```
wp_list_comments( array(
    'callback'      => 'bootstrap_comment_callback',
 ));

function bootstrap_comment_callback( $comment, $args, $depth ){
        $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
    <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class( empty( $args['has_children'] ) ? '' : 'parent' ); ?>>

    <?php if ( 0 != $args['avatar_size'] ): ?>
    <div class="media-left">
        <a href="<?php echo get_comment_author_url(); ?>" class="media-object"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="media-body">
    <?php printf( '<h4 class="media-heading">%s</h4>', get_comment_author_link() ); ?>
    <div class="comment-metadata">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID, $args ) ); ?>">
            <time datetime="<?php comment_time( 'c' ); ?>">
                <?php printf( _x( '%1$s at %2$s', '1: date, 2: time' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() ); ?>
            </time>
        </a>
    </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

    <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
    <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation label label-info"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>             

    <div class="comment-content">
         <?php comment_text(); ?>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-inline">
        <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit' ), '<li class="edit-link">', '</li>' ); ?>

    <?php
        comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array(
            'add_below' => 'div-comment',
            'depth'     => $depth,
            'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'],
            'before'    => '<li class="reply-link">',
            'after'     => '</li>'
        ) ) );  
    ?>
    </ul>
    </div>  
<?php
}
```

---

### Comment Walker

```
wp_list_comments( array(
    'walker'        => new Bootstrap_Comment_Walker(),
 ));

class Bootstrap_Comment_Walker extends Walker_Comment {
    protected function html5_comment( $comment, $depth, $args ) {

?><li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class( empty( $args['has_children'] ) ? '' : 'parent' ); ?>>

    <?php if ( 0 != $args['avatar_size'] ): ?>
    <div class="media-left">
        <a href="<?php echo get_comment_author_url(); ?>" class="media-object"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="media-body">
    <?php printf( '<h4 class="media-heading">%s</h4>', get_comment_author_link() ); ?>
    <div class="comment-metadata">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID, $args ) ); ?>">
            <time datetime="<?php comment_time( 'c' ); ?>">
                <?php printf( _x( '%1$s at %2$s', '1: date, 2: time' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() ); ?>
            </time>
        </a>
    </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

    <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
    <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation label label-info"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>             

    <div class="comment-content">
         <?php comment_text(); ?>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-inline">
        <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit' ), '<li class="edit-link">', '</li>' ); ?>

    <?php
        comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array(
            'add_below' => 'div-comment',
            'depth'     => $depth,
            'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'],
            'before'    => '<li class="reply-link">',
            'after'     => '</li>'
        ) ) );  
    ?>
    </ul>
    </div>      
<?php
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We could rewrite:

```
wp_list_comments( array(
    'callback'      => 'bootstrap_comment_callback',
 ));
```

with the null `walker` parameter:

```
 wp_list_comments( array(
    'walker'        => null,
    'callback'      => 'bootstrap_comment_callback',
 ));
```

which means we are using the default `Walker_Comment` class:

```
  wp_list_comments( array(
    'walker'        => new Walker_Comment,
    'callback'      => 'bootstrap_comment_callback',
 ));
```

The `Walker_Comment::start_el()` method is just a wrapper for one of these *protected* methods:

```
Walker_Comment::comment()
Walker_Comment::html5_comment()
Walker_Comment::ping()
```

that, depending on the context, append each comment to the output string when walking along the comment tree.

Using a *custom walker* class, that extends the `Walker_Comment` class,  gives us the ability to override these *public* methods:

```
Walker_Comment::start_el()
Walker_Comment::end_el()
Walker_Comment::start_lvl()
Walker_Comment::end_lvl()
Walker_Comment::display_element()
```

in addition to the protected ones above.

If we only need to modify the output of the `start_el()` method, we would only need to use the  `callback` parameter in `wp_list_comments()`.

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest of explanations, the `callback` argument for `wp_list_comments()` is used to reference a function that will build the beginning of an **individual** comment. (The `end-callback` argument references a function that will close an individual comment.)

So, you can use your own custom function to output an individual comment while still using the core `Walker_Comment` class to build the **entire** comment list.

Conversely, you could also use your own class to override either all, or parts of, the core `Walker_Comment` class.

In your example above, you defined a custom walker class with one method defined: `html5_comment()`.  Since you're extending the core `Walker_Comment` class, but only overriding one method (`html_comment()`), WP will use the rest of the methods defined in `Walker_Comment` to build out the remainder of the comment list.

Essentially, use `callback`/`end-callback` to build out an individual comment, and use a custom Walker class to build out the entire comment list.  You don't need both, it's one or the other.

Incidentally I just wrote an article outlining this in greater detail based on a plugin I released relating to Bootstrap comments for WordPress.  You can find it here: http://darrinb.com/wp-bootstrap-comments/

Answer (score 0):

> There's some things I can't quite figure out how to change, but the one that's been driving me mad is how to add classes to the children `<ul class="children">` ...

Beside using Walkers and Callbacks, a straight to the point fix would be to do a `preg_replace` before `echo`ing-it-out.

```
<?php

$buffer = wp_list_comments(
    array (
        //...
        'echo' => false,
    ),
    //...
);

$buffer = preg_replace( '/class="children"/', 'class="list-unstyled"', $buffer );

echo $buffer;
```