# Change HTML Produced by wp_list_comments()

Tags: timestamp, comments, comments-template

I am developing a WordPress theme for which I would like each comment's timestamp wrapped in in a `<span>` element for the sake of styling it with CSS rules. However, [the `wp_list_comments()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) as I use it in my theme's `comments.php` template does not seem to provide options to alter the HTML produced:

```
<ol class="comment-list">
    <?php
        wp_list_comments( array(
            'style'       => 'ol',
            'format'      => 'html5',
            'short_ping'  => true,
        ) );
    ?>
</ol>
```

which produces timestamps as such:

```
<time datetime="2015-12-21T19:09:49+00:00"> december 21st,  2015 on 19:09 </time>
```

How can I alter the function's output to include a `<span>`element around each `<time>` element without altering core files?

I've tried looking at my theme's `functions.php`, as well as WordPress `wp-includes/comment.php` and `wp-includes/comment-template.php`. None of them deal with the actual tag structure of the comment timestamps generated by `wp_list_comments()`, so there was nothing there for me to play with.

Comment: Have you seen the [source of `wp_list_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_comments/)? Are you sure this the function responsible and it's not for e.g. the `comments.php` template or a completely different part responsible?

Comment: Are you certain you actually need a `<span>` wrapper? Why not apply styles directly to the `<time>` element?

Comment: I agree with @bosco, it sounds like the `<span>` isn't needed here. Else you should show the arguments to the `wp_list_comments()` function, to see if it's using callback or custom walker. Most likely you're using the built-in  `Walker_Comment::html5_comment()`. A somewhat [related question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216351/comment-walker-vs-comment-callback) was asked here yesterday.

Comment: @birgie my bad - I actually edited out his use of `wp_list_comments()` because I thought it was extraneous. Corrected O.o

Comment: found EXACTLY what i needed in this file: wp-includes/class-walker-comment.php - this is where i could change the html of the comment date. i want to style the time differently than the date, so i needed them in seperate tags. thanks everyone!

Comment: I hope you're not modifying core files directly! @marlakash

Comment: would love to do this otherwise, but not sure how... not much experience with writing plugins and the sort. any tips? @birgire

Comment: BTW i think it's better to keep my previous question title. I would have never found this answer by google. it's way too specific... @birgire

Comment: I put together some options for you, hope you can adjust it to your needs @marlakash

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are some options on how we can override the native layout for each comment:

### Approach #1 - Overriding `start_el()` with a custom walker

Let's define our custom *wpse* comment format:

```
// Arguments for wp_list_comments() 
$args = [
    'style'       => 'ol',
    'format'      => 'html5',
    'short_ping'  => true,
];

// Use our custom walker if it's available
if( class_exists( 'WPSE_Walker_Comment' ) )
{
    $args['format'] = 'wpse';
    $args['walker'] = new WPSE_Walker_Comment;
}

wp_list_comments( $args );
```

with a custom comment walker, that handles this new format (PHP 5.4+):

```
/**
 * Custom comment walker
 *
 * @users Walker_Comment
 */
class WPSE_Walker_Comment extends Walker_Comment
{
    public function start_el( &$output, $comment, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 )
    {
       // Our custom 'wpse' comment format
       if ( 'wpse' === $args['format'] )
       {
           $depth++;
           $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth;
           $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;

           // Start output buffering
           ob_start();

           // Let's use the native html5 comment template
           $this->html5_comment( $comment, $depth, $args );

           // Our modifications (wrap <time> with <span>)
           $output .= str_replace( 
               [ '<time ', '</time>' ], 
               ['<span><time ', '</time></span>' ], 
               ob_get_clean() 
           );
       }
       else
       {
           // Fallback for the native comment formats
           parent::start_el( $output, $comment, $depth, $args, $id );
       }    
    }
} // end class
```

Note how we handle our custom comment format. We also reuse the `start_el()` method from the *parent class* for the native formats, by calling `parent::start_el()`.

Also note that we use the *output buffering* in a similar way as the parent class.

### Approach #2 - Overriding `html5_comment()` with a custom walker

We can also directly override the native `Walker_Comment::html5_comment()` method, in the following way:

```
// Arguments for wp_list_comments() 
$args = [
    'style'       => 'ol',
    'format'      => 'html5',
    'short_ping'  => true,
    'walker'      => new WPSE_Walker_Comment,
];

wp_list_comments( $args );
```

where our custom walker class is in `functions.php` defined as:

```
if ( !class_exists( 'WPSE_Walker_Comment' ) ) {

    /**
     * Custom comment walker
     *
     * @users Walker_Comment
     */
    class WPSE_Walker_Comment extends Walker_Comment {

        public function html5_comment( $comment, $depth, $args ) {
            // Place the modifications of the Walker_Comment::html5_comment() method here
        }
    }
    // end of WPSE_Walker_Comment
} // end of '!class_exists' condition
```

Here we can store our modifications to the [`Walker_Comment::html5_comment()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/26bf8cda9b143936cec33788261dc3d9f8d3654b/wp-includes/class-walker-comment.php#L300-L356) method. It's rather long, so I didn't add it here.

### Approach #3 - Custom callback

Here we would use the `callback` attribute:

```
// Arguments for wp_list_comments() 
$args = [
    'style'       => 'ol',
    'format'      => 'html5',
    'short_ping'  => true,
];

// Use our custom callback if it's available
if( function_exists( 'wpse_comment_callback' ) )
{
    $args['format'] = 'wpse';
    $args['callback'] = 'wpse_comment_callback';
}

wp_list_comments( $args );
```

where we define the `wpse_comment_callback()` to our needs.

```
/**
 * Custom comment callback
 */
function wpse_comment_callback( $comment, $depth, $args )
{
    // Modify the Walker_Comment::html5_comment() method to our needs 
    // and place it here
}
```

where we could start by simulating the [`Walker_Comment::html5_comment()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/26bf8cda9b143936cec33788261dc3d9f8d3654b/wp-includes/class-walker-comment.php#L300-L356) method. But we must remember to replace all reference to `$this`.

### Approach #4 - Overriding `wp_list_comments()` arguments with a filter

We can also use the [`wp_list_comments_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_list_comments_args/) filter to modify the arguments of `wp_list_comments()` with the above methods.

There are other approaches available, but hopefully you can adjust these to your needs.

Comment: Why isn't there a filter for this rather than use OOP.

Comment: The structure of comments tree output is probably too complex to be adjustable through a single text filter.