# Additional content every x comments

Tags: comments, content

Do you have any idea of is it possible to add some content every let’s say 5 comments in WordPress? I could use “more fields” plugin but it would create content after each and every comment. Something like replies containing advertisements, which occurs every 5 forum replies in PhpBB but for WordPress.

e.g.

```
- comment 1  
- comment 2  
- ...  
- comment 5  
- MY CONTENT    
- comment 6  
- ... 
- comment 10  
- MY CONTENT
- comment 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using the following custom input arguments:

```
wp_list_comments( [
    '_inject_period'  => 5,
    '_inject_content' => [ 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC' ],
] );
```

where we setup the inject period and define the content to inject.

This could be supported by the following demo plugin that extends the `\Walker_Comment` class and enhances the `start_el()` method:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Comment Content Injector
 * Plugin URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/251247/26350
 */

add_filter( 'wp_list_comments_args', function( $args )
{   
    // Period - Validation
    if( 
           ! isset( $args['_inject_period'] ) 
        || ! is_int( $args['_inject_period'] )   
        || 0 === $args['_inject_period']  
    )
        return $args;

    // Content - Validation
    if( 
           ! isset( $args['_inject_content'] ) 
        || ! is_array( $args['_inject_content'] ) 
    )
        return $args;

    // Custom Walker
    $args['walker'] = new class extends \Walker_Comment
    {
        public function start_el( &$output, $comment, $depth=0, $args=array(), $id=0 )
        {
            static $instance = 0;
            static $key      = 0;

            $tag = ( 'div' == $args['style'] ) ? 'div' : 'li'; // see Walker_Comment

            // Inject custom content periodically
            if( 
                0 == ++$instance % absint( $args['_inject_period'] ) 
                && isset( $args['_inject_content'][$key] ) 
            ) {
                $output .= sprintf( 
                   '<%s class="injected">%s</%s>', 
                   $tag, 
                   $args['_inject_content'][$key], 
                   $tag 
                );
                $key++;
            }

            // Parent method
            parent::start_el( $output, $comment, $depth, $args, $id );
        }
    };

    return $args;
} );
```

We might also want to adjust this to a given comment depth by checking the `$depth` variable. We could also inject it after the parent method but currently it's before.

Note that here we use an anonymous class. [Here's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/216686/26350) more info on how to extend it without it.

Another approach would be to use the [`comments_array`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/comments_array) filter or if you use a custom callback, adjust it to your needs.

Hope you can adjust it further to your needs!

Comment: Hi, I would like to thank you so much for this. Unfortunately I am getting something like this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in /home/gonzonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/comment-content-injector/index.php on line 25 and I can't activate the plugin. I simply replaced wp list comments inside comments.php and created index.php file where I pasted second part of your code. Than I placed php file inside folder called comment-content-injector and placed it inside plugins folder. Is that corect?

Comment: Most likely your PHP doesn't support the *anonymous class*. You can e.g. check out my answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/216686/26350) how to adjust it accordingly. @user110187

Comment: OK, I got this ;) One more tip - I want to use custom fields inside comments.php file so that I get <?php the_field('custom_title'); ?> in place of AAA here - '_inject_content' => [ 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC' ],. How? Sorry, I'm noob in terms of php

Comment: Looks like you're using ACF, I think `the_field()` function *echos* the value, so you could try `get_field()` instead or just try the `get_post_meta()` core function. @user110187

Comment: erghh not working. Do you have any idea what's wrong here:        `'_inject_content' => [ '<?php the_field('content1'); ?>', 'BBB', 'CCC' ],` or paste your example but exactly?

Comment: Note that you can't use `the_field()` to assign values, only to display it. Did you try `'_inject_content' => [ get_field('content1'), 'BBB', 'CCC' ]`  ? @user110187

Comment: you are my hero ;)

Comment: glad to hear it worked for you ;-) @user110187

Comment: Hi, on one of my websites I have a custom code inside my comments.php file which look like that: `wp_list_comments( array( 
     'callback' => 'generate_comment'
    ) );` How can I add  `'_inject_period'  => 5,
    '_inject_content' => [ 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC' ],` and keep `'generate_comment'` function to work together?

Comment: Ok I worked out with it