# Remove "says" from comments

Tags: functions, comments, css

When using `comments_template()`, all comments starts with `{ Username } says`.

How can I remove that "*says*" part? In most solutions that I found, it suggests using CSS like:

```
.says { display: none; }
```

But the string isn't wrapped in a `div` called `says`.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If you look in your theme folder you should see a file called comments.php. Look in there to see if you have find the area that prints out the username.

You can update that file and save it in a child theme. If you find that is the correct file let me know and I'll make it the answer.

Comment: May you provide us a link to your site where you see "says" in the comment? Each theme varies with their style. This will help me find the actual class name that you need to refer to.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is gonna help. Please try this snippet. Put it in your themes `functions.php` or you could it load it thorough a plugin or any other way-

```
function the_dramatist_remove_says_from_comment( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
    //what text you want to have instead of 'says' in comments. For removing 'says' keep this blank
    $new_var = '';
    $translations = &get_translations_for_domain( $domain );
    if ( $text == '<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>' ) {
        if($new_var) $new_var = ' '.$new_var; //compensate for the space character
        return $translations->translate( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite><span class="says">'.$new_var.':</span>' );
    } else {
        return $translation; // standard text
    }  
}
add_filter('gettext', 'the_dramatist_remove_says_from_comment', 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @the_dramatist is probably the simplest if that's all you want to do, but you can remove it completely and customize everything else as well by creating your own comment template.

As Ethan mentioned in the comment on your question, every theme is different, meaning that most themes have a comment template that is inserting this or are using the default template. If your theme has a custom comment template already, just edit that one otherwise it's using the default [comment function](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5efc557eb8e7306f1aaae0a7abbb1fab12121626/wp-includes/class-walker-comment.php#L328) which includes the comment author says text.

If you have anything else besides that that you'd like to customize you're better off creating your own template or function for this. You can create a [custom callback or custom walker.

Then you'd use wp_list_comments() to output your new comment template.

> So basically here's the process of doing this with templates:

### 1) Create your [callback or comment walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216351/comment-walker-vs-comment-callback) in `functions.php` or similar

### 2) Create a `comments.php` file and call your new function:

**Walker**

```
<?php
wp_list_comments( array(
    'walker' => new Walker_Comment()
) );
```

**Callback**

```
 <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=format_comment'); ?>
```

### 3) Output your comment template on `single.php`

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The class-walker-comment.php file is where you will find a span tag with the style '.says'. So as the original poster mentioned, adding .says{display: none;} to your themes css file will remove the word 'says:'. It worked for me in WP 5.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest fix I've found, just modify css content:

.says {
font-size: 0;
}

.says::after {
content: 'commented on: ';
font-size:1.4rem;
display: inline-block;
}

Answer (score -2):

You need to add a simple function in your functions.php file that allows you to remove or modify or change “Says” word from WordPress comments. Please insert this code into your functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'comment_author_says_text', 'rm_comment_author_says_text' );
function rm_comment_author_says_text() {
    return 'Your Text';
}
```

You will find full instructions here on my website - [Remove or Modify “Says” From WordPress Comments](http://www.ratanmia.com/remove-modify-says-wordpress-comments/)

Comment: Hi Ratan, please take needed information here and [disclosure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: This doesn't work.