# standard callback function for wp_list_comments

Tags: html, callbacks, comments

I know that the code for the comment is generated in `Walker_Comment::comment()` and for html5 themes in the method `Walker_Comment::html5_comment`.

But if I try to copy the code from that last method it does not work because of obvious things like

`$this->hasParent` and so on. I can fix this by using `$comment->hasParent`

Isn't there somewhere a callback I can use which produces the exact same results as the standard code which will work out of the box?

I am using twenty seventeen and would like to change a few thing. I could hack the `class-walker-comment.php` but that would be a bad idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comment Walker vs. Comment Callback](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216351/comment-walker-vs-comment-callback)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're wanting to extend the default comments walker with your own:

```
class My_Walker_Comment extends Walker_Comment {
  // giddy up
}
```

If so, [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/216362/75524) explains it quite well.