# How to display comment meta under each comment content

Tags: comments, comments-template, comment-meta

I'm trying to display comment meta under each comment, but I couldn't find which action should I hook in.

Answer (score 1):

You will need [`get_comment_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_meta) to pull that information from the database. You will need to know the metakey. If you don't have that, you will have to search the theme/plugin that generates the metadata for the occurence of [`add_comment_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta) to find it.

Where to hook depends on how your theme is listing the comments. If it simply uses [`wp_list_comments`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_comments/) there is no filter to simply attach the metadata. You will need to change the callback argument using the `wp_list_comments_args` filter. Then you can make a callback function that specifies which comment and meta data to display and how ([learn more](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216351/comment-walker-vs-comment-callback)).

Comment: thanks for both editing and comments. I'm trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

As an easier alternative, you can use flexbox to reorder the comment items:

```
.comment-list article {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.comment-list .comment-meta,
.comment-list .comment-content {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.comment-list .comment-meta {
    order: 2;
}
```